# ValueError: diff requires input that is at least one dimensional

Tags: python, diff, valueerror, odeint

I studying how to solve differential equations in Python with `odeint` and for test, I try to solve the following ODE (the following example came from of https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SolveDifferentialEquations):

```
# first import the necessary libraries
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# function that returns dy/dt
def model(y,t):
    k = 0.3
    dydt = -k*y
    return dydt

#Initial condition
y0 = 5.0

# Time points
t = np.linspace(0,20)

# Solve ODE
def y(t):
    return odeint(model,y0,t)
```

So if I plot the results with matplotlib, or more simply, give the command `print(y(t))` then this work perfectly! But if I try compute the value of the function for a fixed value of time, for instance, `t1 = t[2]` ( = 0.8163 ) so I get the error

```
t1 = t[2]
print(y(t1))

ValueError("diff requires input that is at least one dimensional")
```

why I only can compute the value for `y(t)` for a interval `t = np.linspace(0,20)` but not for a number in this interval? There is some manner to fix this? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your example does work with python3, numpy 1.12.1 and scipy 0.18.1. Which versions are you using?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy-integrate-odeint

Comment: Thanks for you question: python = 3.5.2, numpy = 1.17, scipy =  1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The `odeint` function solves you differential equation numerically. To do that you need to specify the points where you want your solution to be evaluated. These points also influence the accuracy of the solution. Generally, the more points you give to `odeint` the better the result (when solving the same time interval).

This means that there is no way for `odeint` to know what accuracy you want if you only supply a single time at which you want to evaluate the function. Instead you always need to supply a range of times (like you did with `np.linspace`). `odeint` then returns the value of the solution at all these times.

`y(t)` is an array of values of your solution and the third value in the array corresponds to the solution at the third time in `t`:

The solution evaluated at `t[0]` is `y(t)[0] = y0`
The solution evaluated at `t[1]` is `y(t)[1]`
The solution evaluated at `t[2]` is `y(t)[2]`
...

---

So instead of

```
print(y(t[2]))
```

you need to use

```
print(y(t)[2])
```